# Unable to execute tests from command line via xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, xctest

I am trying to build and run test cases using command line for iOS test cases.
I have given the following command:

```
xcodebuild -target AppEngineTests -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator TEST_AFTER_BUILD=YES clean build
```

It builds the app but the testcases are not run.

could someone please help?
Thanks

Comment: What error messages did you get?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've found the `name` property to require more specification.

```
xcodebuild test -workspace #{WORKSPACE_FILE} -scheme #{TEST_SCHEME} -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone Retina (4-inch),OS=7.0'
```

Was what finally worked for me. `iPhone` was limited and/or unpredictable.

As another poster (can't find the citation) mentioned, the 'platform' loosely corresponds to the divider in the target list, 'name' corresponds to the sub-selection, and the `OS` parameter corresponds to the right side of the chevron in the same list minus 'iOS '.

The documentation is suggestive and sounds authoritative on first glance without actually being full or correct, unfortunately.

Astonishing what a hassle this was. And how well it worked once the right invocation was achieved.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Guillaume, but I had it on multiple lines because it requires scrolling to read otherwise!

Comment: how to make the build for real device

Comment: It's one of the values available to the `destination' parameter, @QadirHussain.

Comment: Just in case someone is reviewing this, now-a-days, it is much easier to manage tests with fastlane and the test actions `scan` or `multi_scan`.

Answer (score 12):

You haven't said what version of Xcode you're using, but since you tagged your question with "xctest" it seems safe to assume you have Xcode 5 or later.

Xcode 5 significantly enhances the support for running tests in `xcodebuild`, via the `test` verb. You'll need to specify a *scheme* and *destination* instead of a target when using this verb, because it acts just like the Test command in the Xcode IDE.

So for example, assuming you have a shared scheme in your project or workspace named AppEngine that has its Test scheme action properly configured, you would be able to just use

```
xcodebuild test -scheme AppEngine -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad'
```

to run all of the unit tests configured for the AppEngine scheme in the iOS Simulator configured as an iPad running the latest iOS. More details on the syntax of the destination specifier are in the [`xcodebuild` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html). (You can even use it to run tests on attached iOS devices!)

The scripts that were previously been used to run unit tests have been adjusted to refer users to the `test` verb instead because with these improvements it's what everyone should be using.

Comment: on 5 that destination syntax gives: xcodebuild: error: option 'Destination' requires at least one parameter of the form 'key=value'. Did you mean 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad'?

Comment: I'm finding this just tests the build and doesn't run the unit tests. Tried it with xcodebuild test <args> and xcodebuild <args> test ... no luck.

Comment: Interesting, the man page claims that the OS version can be specified by using `latest`, but that doesn't appear to work at all.

Comment: Hi, i have used `xcodebuild test -scheme MyApp -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone'` getting below error:xcodebuild: error: _Was unable to find a destination matching the arguments to the -destination flag:
 The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request._

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that you can use `instruments -s devices` to get a list of all available devices.

You should also pass the string as `-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=ID_OF_THE_SIMULATOR'` as for some reason, it doesn't like spaces between the key=value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Xcode build.  In my case the problem was that I didn't have any tests associated with my scheme.

Please see my SO answer (with diagram) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36092189/608569)

Answer (score 0):

Landed here looking for a resolution for similar xcodebuild error. As as addendum, you can also pass a single key=val to -destination e.g `-destination 'platform=iOS'` and xcodebuild will tell you all the alternative available for the scheme.

```
λ ~/Development/app-ios/ task/JIOS-400-Earl-Grey-Spike* xcodebuild -workspace app.xcworkspace -scheme app -destination 'platform=iOS'  -derivedDataPath "build" build-for-testing

User defaults from command line:
    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/schoudhary/Development/app-ios/build

xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { platform:iOS }

    Missing required device specifier option.
    The device type “Generic iOS Device” requires that either “name” or “id” be specified.
    Please supply either “name” or “id”.

    Available destinations for the "App" scheme:
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D248DB01-A852-4360-A9C0-2D71AFE478D7, OS:10.3, name:iPad Air }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CE87AF5A-141C-43DA-AE61-AF53593F37F7, OS:10.3, name:iPad Air 2 }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E93B43E4-D24E-4927-B9EE-0375E15DCBD5, OS:10.3, name:iPad Pro (9.7 inch) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6D71DB17-0FE2-4D5E-BEE6-CC696445BA11, OS:10.3, name:iPad Pro (12.9 inch) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F7E37EF4-5E72-438A-A286-216C20158B47, OS:10.3, name:iPhone 5 }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:24653844-AE99-4B5B-8332-9FFD2208172F, OS:10.3, name:iPhone 5s }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FD2089A4-BF3F-4F98-8E33-B7EFDCFE5B4D, OS:10.3, name:iPhone 6 }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6EF0DFBD-E99E-4EB3-9C51-6E749F41B6E7, OS:10.3, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:846E631C-6285-4B91-9BA6-1AB6E66C88DB, OS:10.3, name:iPhone 6s }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A6943ADC-F6EF-42F6-9958-D966DFC419FC, OS:10.3, name:iPhone 6s Plus }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B41ABED0-7554-438A-97AC-F34943ED4D79, OS:10.3, name:iPhone 7 }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:20F1582C-0D19-4F42-9DAD-43138FB923B9, OS:10.3, name:iPhone 7 Plus }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:683BB5CA-E0A8-4CE4-B0DD-AED4C4295B90, OS:10.3, name:iPhone SE }

    Ineligible destinations for the "App" scheme:
        { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Device }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Simulator Device }
```

just another useful way to get the right destination.