# How to settings jenkins correctly to make continous integration jenkins xcode freestyle build success?

Tags: xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I follow this [article](https://medium.com/livefront/basic-continuous-integration-with-jenkins-xcode-and-github-e999673e73b4) about Basic Continuous Integration with Jenkins, Xcode, but failed to get green on jenkins build

I try all article step but still cannot jenkins build success, always failure.

I use Jenkins 2.426.1

My Scheme are :
[jenkins test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bK9v.png)
[jenkins build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2bqx.png)

Additional xcodebuild arguments :
test -scheme jenkins -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14 Pro,OS=16.4'

Test report XMLs :
"${WORKSPACE}/freestyle-jenkins/test-reports/*.xml"

Failure message are :

Touch /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jenkins-bypqnpxdthiwpfdzvpooneqdtvcy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/jenkins/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/jenkins.app (in target 'jenkins' from project 'jenkins')
cd /Users/username/.jenkins/workspace/freestyle-jenkins
/usr/bin/touch -c /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jenkins-bypqnpxdthiwpfdzvpooneqdtvcy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/jenkins/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/jenkins.app

** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **

--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:EA8412BD-B353-4AF4-AA1B-97251151B525, OS:16.4, name:iPhone 14 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:EA8412BD-B353-4AF4-AA1B-97251151B525, OS:16.4, name:iPhone 14 Pro }
2023-11-07 11:55:53.356 xcodebuild[75683:5834271] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/wm/_w_xrj315rb1mx733kpfq27c0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2023-07-11_11-55-0053.xcresult
Prepare packages
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build project jenkins with scheme jenkins.: Tests cannot be run because the test plan “jenkins” could not be read.
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
Recording test results
No test report files were found. Configuration error?
Finished: FAILURE

I try to search why [Tests cannot be run because the test plan “jenkins” could not be read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481630/xcode-project-scheme-is-not-currently-configured-for-the-test-action) but after follow other article step, still got failure.

Please help me to finish jenkins freestyle build and test success